# Problem converting a Pandas dataframe column of Unix format dates (from yfinance) into datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, yfinance

I found a bunch of examples for changing unix date to datetime format (albeit, not necessarily in the columns of a dataframe), and as far as I can see they don't seem to work for me.

For reference, the index column is getting its date from a yfinance dataframe, in the 13 number 'seconds' format.

I've tried numerous variations for the locations of 'datetime' and 'dt', including 'import datetime as datetime'.

Is there a glaringly obvious reason the snippet of code below doesn't work?

```
##      Code from start of file
        import datetime as dt
        from datetime import datetime


##      Make a copy of index column to make unix dates easier to work with
        df['UnixDate'] = df.index

##      Trying to create a column with the datetime format date in
        timestamp = df['UnixDate']
        unix_conversion = datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        df['DateCol'] = unix_conversion

##      Other things tried
##      df["DateCol"] = datetime.fromtimestamp(df["UnixDate"]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')        
##      df["DateCol"] = df["Date"]
##      df['DateCol'] = datetime.fromtimestamp(df['UnixDate']).strftime('%Y-%m')
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `datetime` class can only handle scalar values. Your `timestamp` variable is an instance of class `pd.Series`.

Use `pd.to_timestamp` instead:

```py
df['DateCol'] = pd.to_datetime(df['UnixDate'], unit='ms')
```

Comment: I might be using this wrong, but I'm getting another column of Unix dates from this?

Comment: What does your `UnixDate` column look like? Can you include a few examples?

Comment: So these are sequential days (minus any weekends or market holidays): `"UnixDate":1485216000000, "UnixDate":1485302400000, "UnixDate":1485388800000`       edited now, I pressed return too soon!

Comment: Try with `unit='ms'`. UNIX epoch time is measured in seconds. But data provider may supply data at the millisecond or nanosecond resolution

Comment: Your first solution did work. I reviewed the data after it had been converted into JSON format with `df.to_json(orient="records")`. I have now run the `df` in the console and see the date is the right format, but unfortunately the conversion to JSON seems to be converting back to a Unix date. I think I will deal with this problem in the Javascript rather than the Python code. Thanks for your help getting me this far.

Comment: JSON does not have a date/time format. Different library handle it in different ways. Some serialize date/time into strings using RFC 8601 format (yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SSZ) and some serialize it into integers as second, millisecond or nanosecond since Jan 1, 1970